# Contact Form Plugin: Validate if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: validation, plugin-contactform

What is the cleanest way to validate if a checkbox (i.e. agree to legal terms) is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no clean way doing this without making changes to the plugin itself. The  [`contactForm.beforeSend`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm#the-contactformbeforesend-event) event makes it possible to prevent the email from being sent from another plugin, but you're only being passed the compiled email message as a string. It's probably possible to post you checkbox data with that string and parse for it in your event listener, but you asked for a clean solution! :)

So fork the plugin and add a new attribute to the ContactFormModel:

```
'agreedToTerms' => array(AttributeType::Enum, 'required' => true, 'values' => array(true)),
```

And make the ContactFormController get the attribute value from your form:

```
$message->agreedToTerms = craft()->request->getPost('agreedToTerms');
```

You're now all set add a checkbox "agreedToTerms" to your form and add a custom error message in case the model attribute failed validation:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="agreedToTerms" value="true" {{ message is defined and message.agreedToTerms ? 'checked' }}> Agree the Terms and Conditions</label>

{% if message is defined and message.hasErrors('agreedToTerms') %}
    <ul class="errors"><li>{{ 'You must agree the Terms and Conditions'|t }}</li></ul>
{% endif %}
```